# Is there any way to choose a specific microphone as AudioSource for Audio recording with the help of MicrophoneInfo?

Tags: firebase, android-audiomanager, android-audiorecord

I'm working on an app that will diagnose each microphone available in the device. I'm able to get all microphone info using [MicroPhoneInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#getMicrophones()). How to pass each microphone as an audio source for the recorder. Is it possible?

mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);

Answer (score 1):

Usually there are two microphones:
`MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC`

and `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER`

second is usually is on the back of the phone.